# create a div containing sliding images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div inside which I have placed images of many languages. The total size of the div goes above the page size in a browser. So I want the images to keep moving from bottom to top like animation slider. Image size is not what I am looking to change. I just want the images to keep moving from bottom to top. At the end of this website http://www.veepal.com/ there is a div that has images of different programming languages which keep sliding. I want similar functionality. Is it possible??

```
 <div id="languagesRow" style="position: absolute;top:5px;">
              <div id="l1"><img class="messagesOne"  src="images/languages/English.png"></div>
              <div id="l2"><img class="messagesOne"  src="images/languages/French.png"></div>
              <div id="l3"><img class="messagesOne"  src="images/languages/Russian.png"></div>
              <div id="l4"><img class="messagesOne"  src="images/languages/Chinese.png"></div>
              <div id="l5"><img class="messagesOne"  src="images/languages/Korean.png"></div>
              <div id="l6"><img class="messagesOne"  src="images/languages/Hindi.png"></div>


          </div>
```

I dont know what can be used more optimally to achieve this kind of animation so I am tagging jquery, javascript and css in this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use marquee for this:

> **http://jsfiddle.net/ZB2Fc/**

```
<div class='flags'>
    <MARQUEE BEHAVIOR='SCROLL' HEIGHT='25' WIDTH='300' BGColor='yellow' scrollamount="1" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
        <div id="l1">English</div>
        <div id="l2">French </div>
        <div id="l3">Russian </div>
        <div id="l4">Chinese </div>
    </MARQUEE>
</div>
```

Comment: I would ask you one same favor I asked the other person who answered, the items inside the marquee(in my case images) start being visible one by one and then disappear completely and then again reappear. Is there a way that this could look like a cyclic operation, as in when last image goes comes up it is immediately foolowed by first image?? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

CSS Marquee is one option : http://jsfiddle.net/FbKW9/

```
<marquee  behavior="scroll" direction="up" >//item</marquee>
```

Comment: Thanks this was a great solution with exact desired functionality. Only one thing, the items inside the marquee(in my case images) start being visible one by one and then disappear completely and then again reappear. Is there a way that this could look like a cyclic operation, as in when last image goes comes up it is immediately foolowed by first image??